# Use decorators check user login in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I defined a check user method:

```
from functools import wraps

def check_user(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if session['logged_in']:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return '<a href="/#/login">Log in</a>'
    return wrapper

@app.route('/test')
@check_user
def test():
    return "Hello"
```

It does not work. how can I correct it?

Comment: yep,it not work now.how will  i do ?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you don't know how to create decorators in python. There are many helpful answers on this question: [How can I make a chain of function decorators in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python)

Below is how you can create a decorator that checks if a user is logged in.

```
from functools import wraps

def checkuser(func):
    """Checks whether user is logged in or raises error 401."""
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not g.user:
            abort(401)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

The decorator above will raise a 401 error if a user is not logged in. It will return the view function otherwise.